# Use Makefile + Eclipse + Mac + g++ + mpic++

Tags: eclipse, macos, gcc, makefile

I have installed gcc 5.3.0(g++) and compiled mpich(mpic++) using that.
I already have my own Makefile, when i make from command line everything perfectly.

I also imported the project to eclipse PTP (Mars) and set the build option to make and set build folder to my source folder. Added my mpic++ and g++ paths to eclipse path environment variable.

When i build from eclipse, it finds and executes my make command, it even finds out my mpic++ but internally its using clang but not gcc

When i check mpic++ version on command line, i get

```
MacBook-Pro:mpi$ mpic++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And i added the same command to my make file so that i can check whats happening on eclipse, I get this

```
( mpic++ --version; )
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

So i am not sure what i missed here. How do i change my eclipse to use gcc instead of clang?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you do to get `mpic++` to use `gcc` in the first place? Did you have to set a custom `PATH` anywhere?

Comment: I used the `CC`, `CXX` option during `./configure`. Also I have `PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH` set to appropriate folders

Comment: Are those set in the environment that eclipse is using? Specifically `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` can't be exported to many processes on El Capitan anymore.

Comment: I have only `PATH, CPATH` set in eclipse, because all i need is to compile and not link. My make does a bunch of `-c` compilations. I am basically using this to check for synatx errors, when i actually build (compile & link) i can use command line